# No se importa Bootstrap en proyecto Django

Tags: python, bootstrap, django

Estoy en la curva de aprendizaje de Django. Estoy intentando agregar Bootstrap en un pequeño ejercicio pero no me esta mostrando el estilo.

> Esta es la estructura del proyecto.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Archivo urls.py de libreria

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.inicio, name="inicio"),
    path('nosotros', views.nosotros, name="nosotros")
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

> Archivo views.py de libreria

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
# Create your views here.

def inicio(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h1>Hola Amigo</h1>")

def nosotros(request):
    return render(request, 'paginas/nosotros.html')
```

> Archivo nosotros.html de libreria

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>  
<html lang="en"> 
<head>  
    <meta charset="UTF-8">  
    <title>Title</title>  
    <link href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}">  
    <script src="{% static 'js/bootstrap.min.js' %}"></script>  
    <script>alert("Hola mundo");</script>  
</head>  
<body>  
    <form action="/save" method="post">  
        <div class="form-group">  
          <label for="email">Email address:</label>  
          <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email">  
        </div>  
        <div class="form-group">  
          <label for="pwd">Password:</label>  
          <input type="password" class="form-control" id="pwd">  
        </div>  
        <div class="checkbox">  
          <label><input type="checkbox"> Remember me</label>  
        </div>  
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>  
      </form>
</body>  
</html>
```

> Resultado final.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> Documentos de CSS y JS

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hice todo tal cual esta en el video pero no se me muestran los estilos a mi.

Espero que me puedan apoyar a detectar mi error.

Saludos y que tengan un excelente martes.

Comment: Hola, podrias compartir que archivos tienes en static/js y en static/css

Comment: Claro, edito la pregunta y checas actualización.

Comment: @lankos ya edite la pregunta y coloque lo que me faltaba.

Comment: ¿Ya probaste borrar la cache del navegador?, cuando agrego estilos nuevos a Django suelo borrar la cache ya que en ocasiones no se reflejan los cambios.

Comment: Cual es tu `STATIC_URL` el settings.py?

Comment: @JoseColin ya borre cache y persiste el error.

Comment: @loki trae una por defecto la cual es STATIC_URL = '/static/'

Comment: @Javierfr, aparte de STATIC_URL = '/static/' igual declaraste STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)  ?

Answer (score 0):

Acorde [a la documentación](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/howto/static-files/#configuring-static-files) y viendo tu estructura del proyecto te falta meter los ccs/js en un folder dedicado a la aplicación. Ejemplo `app1/static/app1/css/...`.

Si necesitas que sean globales a todas las apps debes de definir `STATICFILES_DIRS`

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static",
]
```